# Error ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

int main(void){
double list;
double get_average(const double list[], int n);
int i;
double sum = 0;
int n[SIZE];
 for (i = 0; i<n; ++i){
   sum += list [i];
  }
return(sum);
}
```

I know this is a very simple code (newbie to CS) but I get error I stated in the title. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are comparing an `int` to an `int[10]` in `i<n`; that doesn't make sense. Use `SIZE`.

Comment: `list` is a _scalar_ variable and _not_ an _array_. So, you want (e.g.) `double list[1000];` or `double *list = malloc(sizeof(*list) * 1000);`. But, even then, `list` will _not_ have been _initialized_ so you'll have UB (undefined behavior).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And why are you compiling C code with a C++ compiler?

Comment: Well uh... We are using Dev C++at C lessons. Not questioning why.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. -- DevC++ is "just" an IDE, you can compile C, C++, and mixed programs. However, you should know what kind of project you created. Oh, and while we are talking about IDEs: Please raise the warning level to the maximum and follow a zero-warnings-zero-errors strategy. -- For which line do you get the error? You might want to [edit] your question and mark it directly in the source with a comment. -- In addition to Neil's comment: What do you want to express with `i<n`?